# RecyclerView notifyDataSetChanged IllegalStateException

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I wana create mobile application that uses RecyclerView with pagination that loads each time from dataBase 10 items, then when the list reaches the bottom I load 10 other items, so I used this metho to be notified if I reached the end of the list :

```
public boolean reachedEndOfList(int position) {
        // can check if close or exactly at the end
        return position == getItemCount() - 1;
    }
```

and I used this function to load items :

```
 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(Info holder, int position, List<Object> payloads) {
        if (reachedEndOfList(position)) {
            Log.d("reachedEnd", "true");
            this.autoCompletesTmp = getTmp();
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
```

getTmp() update the list of items with another 10 items, but i get this exception when I reached the bottom of the list:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call this method while RecyclerView is computing a layout or scrolling
```

Comment: Why are you calling `notifyDataSetChanged` on `onBindViewHolder`?

Comment: because there I could know the position of the view Item  and call my method "reachedEndOfList(int position)" to know if i reached the bottom of he list

Comment: explain this :             this.autoCompletesTmp = getTmp();

Comment: that mean i update my list with 10 other items

Comment: Do it in an async task and notify in onPostExecute.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem a while ago:
This helped:

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
                final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {

                        //Do something like notifyDataSetChanged()
                    }
                };

                handler.post(r);
```